# Unable to sign up using Firebase Auth in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for my app, I have set up everything properly and Firebase Firestore is working without any problem and I am able to Read and Write data there but when I tried to create a user in Firebase I am getting this message in debug console:

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 2228): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@fc008c3
W/DynamiteModule( 2228): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth( 2228): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
I/lutter_firebase( 2228): type=1400 audit(0.0:1201): avc: denied { sendto } for path="/dev/socket/logdw" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_dgram_socket permissive=1
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228): Timeout waiting for ServiceConnection callback com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228): java.lang.Exception
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.handleMessage(Unknown Source:53)
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zze.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:8)
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
E/GmsClientSupervisor( 2228):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
W/DynamiteModule( 2228): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth( 2228): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

Here is the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: chat_app_flutter_firebase
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

auth_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import '../widgets/auth/auth_form.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var _isLoading = false;

  void _submitAuthForm(
    String email,
    String password,
    String username,
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx,
  ) async {
    AuthResult authResult;

    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      if (isLogin) {
        authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } else {
        authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        await Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(authResult.user.uid)
            .setData({
          'username': username,
          'email': email,
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      var message = 'An error occurred, pelase check your credentials!';

      if (err.message != null) {
        message = err.message;
      }

      Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(message),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
        ),
      );
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: AuthForm(
        _submitAuthForm,
        _isLoading,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

auth_form.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  AuthForm(
    this.submitFn,
    this.isLoading,
  );

  final bool isLoading;
  final void Function(
    String email,
    String password,
    String userName,
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx,
  ) submitFn;

  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _isLogin = true;
  var _userEmail = '';
  var _userName = '';
  var _userPassword = '';

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      widget.submitFn(_userEmail.trim(), _userPassword.trim(), _userName.trim(),
          _isLogin, context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email address',
                    ),
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userEmail = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  if (!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('username'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                          return 'Please enter at least 4 characters';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userName = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be at least 7 characters long.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userPassword = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 12),
                  if (widget.isLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Signup'),
                      onPressed: _trySubmit,
                    ),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    FlatButton(
                      textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      child: Text(_isLogin
                          ? 'Create new account'
                          : 'I already have an account'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have previously worked on a similar app with older Flutter SDK and everything worked just fine.

Current Flutter SDK Info:

Flutter 1.17.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e6b34c2b5c (9 days ago) • 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700     ,
Engine • revision 540786dd51
Tools • Dart 2.8.1

**GitHub repo** : [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/TheKetan2/chat_app_flutter_firebase)

Any Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you  please use this dependency firebase_auth: ^0.16.0? and let me know if it works, Also, please restart the app

Comment: I hope that works for you or still struggling?

Comment: I tried it but sadly it's still not working.

Comment: please check the firebase auth rule if you modified any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my Emulator, ran it on the physical device and it worked.

I was using Genymotion emulator and it did not have Play Store installed in it, so I installed them using GApps and this solved the issue from emulator too.

Also, using emulator from Android Studio having Play Store services does the trick.